# Interface builder "Automatic" class is not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I've had this problem before, and normally restarting XCode seems to fix the problem.

In my storyboard I have setup bot a custom class for the controller and the main view. To the view I hook up my outlets. But this only works if it is selected in "automatic" in the Assistant Editor.

[image: "Automatic section" Assistant Editor]

But it doesn't seem to find my custom view class (CEXWebView). It seems that Xcode doesn't find any of my custom views anymore. Even though they always did work.

I've restarted Xcode, my Mac, changed it back to UIView and back. Wen't through the "manual" section to get the view (sometimes it popped up under Automatic then). But nothing works.

It does seem to work in Xcode 6 beta 3. So I don't think it is my code. But there I get a few other errors unrelated to this problem. Working in Xcode 5 is preferred.

To clarify.

[image: Setup]

How I've set it up is that my main view is a custom class. Where I want to hook its subviews to via an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to select your custom view on Storyboard and you'll find your custom classes in **Class** section

[image]

Comment: I don't think that works. My "root view" is a custom view. If I set the Assistant editor on "Class" when I select another subview the item changes (and thus the class) and I can't hook that item up via an IBOutlet in my "root view".

Comment: @Matthijn if you have set the class of your custom view properly in Storyboard then by default it will show that class in "Class" section. And it will show all the parent classes in "Automatic" section. Take a look at this screenshot where I have used 3 views. 2 of those 3 views are custom views. [Screenshot](http://goo.gl/7UE2bY)

Comment: You should hook new items that you need for your subView to the class of the subView and not to the rootView. Rather have a reference of your subView in the rootView and create properties to modify those items from rootView. That way you will keep the codes and logics separate in two different classes.